# Генерация сертификатов прокси

Tags: https, openssl

Реализую https прокси.
Как я понимаю я должен осуществить следующую последовательность действий:

1. сгенерировать собственный сертификат
2. добавить его в браузер в раздел "центры сертификации"
3. каждый раз при запросе на https страничку генерировать для неё сертификат подписанный первым.

Собственно вопрос, правильно ли я иду?

И какие команды в openssl я должен выполнить для генерации таких сертификатов?

Comment: Правильно было бы не изобретать велосипед, а использовать любое из существующих решений для этого неприятного дела.

Comment: Например? Из тех что с открытым кодом и под Винду.....я не смог найти

Comment: Под винду их и нет, вам под линус надо